# Polymorphic identity on different files

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a Python project with SQLAlchemy and I have 2 classes - base class and child class. The child class inherits from the base class and being used as a polymorphic identity for the base class’s type field.

File 1:

```
class Animal(Base):
    __tablename__ = "animals"
    animal_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    animal_type = Column(String)
    family = Column(String)

    @staticmethod
    def init(animal_id):
        return Sessions.main.query(Animal).filter_by(animal_id=animal_id).first()

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_on": animal_type,
        "polymorphic_identity": "animals"
}
```

File 2:

```
from animal.animal import Animal

class Lion(Animal):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity" = "lion"
    }
```

The two classes are placed in different files, but when I initiate an animal instance (which actually supposed to be initiated as a lion instance) instance, it raises an exception with `No such polymorphic identity` although it does exist, but in another file.

```
    lion = Animal.init('lionid1')
AssertionError: No such polymorphic identity 'lion' is defined
```

When I move the `Lion` class to the same file where the `Animal` class is, the initialization succeeds, but it's not the solution I want because both of those classes will eventually be too big for one file.

I also cannot import the `Lion` class to the base class's file because the child class inherits from the base class and then both of them import each other which causes an error as well:

```
    from lion.lion import Lion  # added on the top of file 1 
ImportError: cannot import name 'Lion'
```

Any ideas on how to solve it? How can I position those two classes in different files without causing any of these errors?

Comment: Please, be careful with code you write in a text editor; all your single and double quotes have been replaced with fancy quoting, which is invalid in Python code.

Comment: For future reference, you can (and should) edit your [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345304/sqlalchemy-polymorphic-identity-on-another-file), and it will be automatically put in reopen queue: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue

Answer (score 0):

You still need to import that module **somewhere**, otherwise the class never is registered. Just don't import it at the top of the `animal.animal` module.

You could import it at a the package level, or at the bottom of the `animal.animal` module (so *after* creating the base `Animals` class). Importing it makes SQLAlchemy aware that it exists.

Comment: Well, it seemed to make the import and the no such polymorphic identity errors disappear but then caused another error: “SQLAlchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table ‘animals’ is already defined for this MetaData instance. Specify ‘extend_existing=True’ to redefine options and columns on an existing Table objects. I made sure I have no duplicates, and added this ‘extend_existing’ to the existing class and this error went away. But then the import error came back again. The both files imports each other, the import of the lion file is made on the bottom of animal file, and still...

Comment: @GalShahar: that import error will be different then, you may have *more* circular imports. You haven't given us a proper [mcve] so I really can't say more here.